SharePoint list with people column doesn't show Persona Card when you hover over the picture?
SharePoint list with people column doesn't show the Persona Card when you hover over the picture !
Can this be solved ?
Gr. P

Are you using list in modern experience? Can you share a screenshot of list view with test data?

I can not. Because of security reasons

I forgot to mention that i have the list as Compact View

Oh and i have the sharepoint list added as tab in Teams. In Sharepoint it works but not in Teams.

That's a lot of important details :)

Does it work in Teams in browser?
Does it work in Teams in Desktop version?
How do you open the SharePoint list in Teams? Did you add a tab of SharePoint site?
Can you please share screenshots?
The behaviour of a personal card differs depending on a configuration and what you experience may be by design.
